# Get folder depth from a virtual path

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm trying to get the folder position from a given path
The path it self is not accessible therefore i cannot use the `Directory` nor `DirectoryInfo` class [Reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316009/c-sharp-best-way-to-get-folder-depth-for-a-given-path/316016#316016)

the result should be something like:

1. C:\ **returns** -1
2. c:\FolderA **returns** 0
3. c:\FolderA\FolderB **returns** 1

I'm using the following but the result between 1 and 2 is the same :-(:

```
  public static int GetFolderLevelDepth(string fullPath)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullPath))
            {
                return -99;
            }
            int result = fullPath.Count(x => x == '\\');
            return result -2;
        }
```

**Test:**

```
[Test]
    public void Get_Level_Root_Depth_Test()
    {
        var result = StringModifier.GetFolderLevelDepth("c:\\");
        Assert.AreEqual(-1,result);
    }
    [Test]
    public void Get_Level_One_Depth_Test()
    {
        var result = StringModifier.GetFolderLevelDepth("c:\\Folder1");
        Assert.AreEqual(0, result);
    }
    [Test]
    public void Get_Level_Two_Depth_Test()
    {
        var result = StringModifier.GetFolderLevelDepth("c:\\Folder1\\Folder2");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should account for the most likely input conditions:

```
int res = -99;
string input = fullPath.Trim();
if (input.Length > 0 && input.Contains(@"\"))
{
    if (input.Substring(input.Length - 1, 1) == @"\") input = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1);
    res = input.Split('\\').Length - 2;
}
return res;
```

Comment: @Maro Yes (I thought that you might need that) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
fullPath = fullPath.Trim();
if (fullPath[fullPath.Length - 1] != '\\')
    return fullPath.Count(x => x == '\\') - 1;
return fullPath.Count(x => x == '\\') - 2;
```

Or :

```
return fullPath.Split('\\').Length - 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this instead:

```
result = fullPath.Split('\\', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
```

`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` causes it to discard the last entry if the path ends with a backslash; which causes the code to not count the "empty directory name" at the end.

Note that this code won't take into account the *current directory* (`.`) and *parent directory* (`..`) special directories, though.